# Uaac install: Permission denied error and Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-elcapitan, predix

Currently we are using mac version OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.

```
Gem version : 2.5.1 and
ruby version : ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION' 
"OpenSSL 1.0.2g 1 Mar 2016"
```

which ruby

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
```

gem env

[image]

We tried like this

```
$ gem install cf-uaac
$ gem install cf-uaac --source http://rubygems.org 
$ gem install cf-uaac  -v 3.3.0
```

We got this

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.9.1/.gitignore
```

We need install `UAAC`

if we using sudo 
we got error this

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cf-uaac' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

We are working Setting Up Your `Predix Mobile Development Environment`

Comment: If you are using the system Mac OS ruby, you have to use a `sudo` before `gem install` to save that gem in your system. Have you tried using sudo ?

Comment: @tGeek thanks for reply yes we are using SUDO also if we using with sudo we got error 
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cf-uaac' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Please guide to us.

Comment: Is your Ruby gems updated ? Try `sudo gem install update --system` and try again. Your error message says that the gem is not there in the package site fot your installed gem version. Give it a try.

Comment: Or you can simply remove the ssl one and put simple http with the following 2 commands `sudo gem source -a http://rubygems.org`
`sudo gem source --remove https://rubygems.org` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any proxies set up in your profile which might not allow you to hit rubygems.

Also, rubygems is https.